# Using NIntegrate to integrate functions with sharp peaks (Lorentzian-like)

Tags: numerical-integration

I have a problem with [`NIntegrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate.html) that I do not understand. I want to integrate a function `f[x]`, which has a complicated analytic expression, but appears as a sum of narrow *Lorentzian* peaks. The function is defined so that $0 \leq f(x) \leq 1$ for all $x$:

```
Plot[f[x], {x, -0.9, 0}, PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> "f[x]"]
```

[image: f(x)]

If I now integrate the function numerically in the plotted interval, I get an unrealistically high result:

```
NIntegrate[f[x], {x, -0.9, 0}, Method -> "MonteCarlo"]

NIntegrate::maxp: The integral failed to converge after 50100 integrand evaluations. NIntegrate obtained 3.111064646506622`*^24 and 9.60509125990105`*^22 for the integral and error estimates. >>

3.11106*10^24
```

I tried to play around with different Nintegration methods, but the same order of magnitide shows up as a result. After some inspection, I found that the large contribution is located around $x= -0.81$. But here, $f(x)$ takes tiny values.

Does anyone know why I get this huge value? The same behavior of the function shows up when I use immediate definition:

```
g[x_] = f[x];
Plot[g[x], {x, -0.825, -0.8}, PlotPoints -> 150, PlotLabel -> "g[x]"]
```

[image: g[x]]

Comment: I think you should share the definiton of your function too.

Comment: Why exactly do you insist on using Monte Carlo for a one-dimensional integral? There certainly are better methods of proceeding.

Comment: Hard to guess at why an unknown function evaluates in a way that is unexpected.

Answer (score 7):

The `NIntegrate` behavior you observe over your integrand is described and explained in the section ["Examples of Pathological Behavior"](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationRules.html#8354729) in the chapter ["NIntegrate Integration Rules"](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationRules.html) of the [Advanced NIntegrate documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateOverview.html) .

Using larger values for the options `MinRecursion`, `MaxRecursion`, and `PrecisionGoal` would probably fix your issue.

```
NIntegrate[f[x], {x, 0, 1}, PrecisionGoal -> 12, MinRecursion -> 12, 
 MaxRecursion -> 20]
```

**Longer answer with code**

The estimates and plot shown below illustrate how the overestimation can happen.

[image]

The plot shows the integrand and the polynomials corresponding to the abscissas and weights of the Gauss-Kronrod integration rule.

Below is the code for the image above. I used the code from the cited document and an integrand function generated in a fashion similar to that of the answer of Dr. belisarius.

```
Clear[f]
f[x_] := 318.31/(1 + 1.*^6*(-0.49158 + x)^2) + 
  318.31/(1 + 1.*^6*(-0.478 + x)^2)

Plot[f[x], {x, 0.3, 0.8}, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
 PlotPoints -> 10000, PlotRange -> All]

{absc, weights, errweights} = 
  NIntegrate`GaussKronrodRuleData[12, MachinePrecision];

Clear[FitPlots];
FitPlots[f_, {a_, b_}, abscArg_] := 
  Module[{absc = 
     Rescale[abscArg, {0, 1}, {a, 
       b}]},(*this finds the interpolating polynomial through the \
Gauss abscissas and the values of f over them*)
   polyGauss[x_] := 
    Evaluate[
     InterpolatingPolynomial[
      Transpose[{Take[absc, {2, -2, 2}], 
        f[#1] & /@ (Take[absc, {2, -2, 2}])}], x]];
   (*this finds the interpolating polynomial through the Gauss-
   Kronrod abscissas and the values of f over them*)
   polyGaussKronrod[x_] := 
    Evaluate[
     InterpolatingPolynomial[Transpose[{absc, f[#1] & /@ absc}], x]];
   (*plot of the Gauss interpolating points*)
   samplPointsGauss = 
    Graphics[{GrayLevel[0], PointSize[0.02], 
      Point /@ 
       Transpose[{Take[absc, {2, -2, 2}], 
         f[#1] & /@ Take[absc, {2, -2, 2}]}]}];
   (*plot of the Gauss-Kronrod interpolating points*)
   samplPointsGaussKronrod = 
    Graphics[{Red, PointSize[0.012], 
      Point /@ Transpose[{absc, f[#1] & /@ absc}]}];
   (*interpolating polynomials and f plots*)

   Block[{$DisplayFunction = Identity},
    funcPlots = Plot[{
        Tooltip[polyGauss[x], "Gauss"],
        Tooltip[polyGaussKronrod[x], "Gauss-Kronrod"],
        Tooltip[f[x], "Integrand"]}, {x, a, b},
       PlotRange -> All, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
       PlotPoints -> 10000, 
       PlotLegends -> {"Gauss", "Gauss-Kronrod", "Integrand"}];];
   exact = Integrate[f[x], {x, a, b}];
   r1 = Integrate[polyGauss[x], {x, a, b}];
   r2 = Integrate[polyGaussKronrod[x], {x, a, b}];
   Print["estimated integral:" <> ToString@InputForm@r2, 
    "  exact integral:" <> ToString@InputForm@Re@exact];
   Print["estimated error:" <> ToString@InputForm@Abs[r1 - r2], 
    "  actual error:" <> ToString@InputForm@Abs[r2 - exact]];
   Show[{funcPlots, samplPointsGauss, samplPointsGaussKronrod}]
   ];

grRes = FitPlots[f[#1] &, {0.4, 0.55}, absc]
```

Answer (score 6):

You may try for example:

```
(* Lorentzians*)

f[x_] := Tr@Evaluate@Table[PDF[CauchyDistribution[a, .0001], x], 
                           {a, RandomReal[{.1, .9}, 10]}]

Plot[Evaluate@f[x], {x, 0, 1}, Filling -> Axis, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
NIntegrate[f[x], {x, 0, 1}, Method -> "LocalAdaptive"]
(* 9.99831 *) (*Quite good,should be 10 *)
```

Answer (score 5):

Another possibility for integrating functions with wildly varying features is to avoid `NIntegrate[]` altogether, and consider reformulating as an initial value problem that can then be handled by `NDSolve[]`. Since [DE solvers are often more careful than quadrature routines](https://mathoverflow.net/a/47776), they are less likely to miss sharp peaks or other features that usually give quadratures trouble.

Thus,

```
BlockRandom[SeedRandom[0]; (* bel's/Michael's example *)
            f[x_] = Sum[PDF[CauchyDistribution[a, .0001], x],
                        {a, RandomReal[{.1, .9}, 10]}]];

AbsoluteTiming[NDSolveValue[{y'[x] == f[x], y[0] == 0}, y[1], {x, 1, 1},
                            Method -> "Extrapolation"]]
   {0.118919, 9.998274818835679}
```

(Thanks to Michael for pointing out a more compact way to evaluate the resulting `InterpolatingFunction[]` at the terminal value.)

Comment: +1 (earlier). By way of comparison with my timing, I get `{0.015616`, 9.998275411135387`} ` with your code on my machine -- much faster in this case (V10.3.1, Macbook Pro).  I also got a slightly different value for the integral.  My experience is that `NIntegrate` is usually slower but more accurate. But a few extra digits probably doesn't matter in scientific applications (`NDSolve` gets almost 8, `NIntegrate` almost 12).  Finally you can obtain the value more directly with `NDSolveValue[..., y[1], {x, 1, 1},...]`.

Comment: @Michael, I hadn't adjusted `AccuracyGoal`/`PrecisionGoal` tho, so anyone who wants to squeeze out a few more digits would want to adjust those. However, as you say, 8-12 digits might be more than enough in most empirical applications.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, and it's a bit like comparing apples and oranges. I recall a couple of cases where I couldn't achieve the precision goal with `NDSolve` as easily as with `NIntegrate` (which will automatically extend the precision of the numbers when the going gets tough).  Maybe they were edge cases.  Seems to be different in this case.  Perhaps I got the wrong general impression.

Answer (score 3):

If the function is like that of [@Dr. b.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/193/dr-belisarius), one might divide the interval up programmatically, to help `NIntegrate` find the important regions and still use a `"GlobalAdaptive"` strategy.

Dr. belisarius's Lorentzians:

```
(*Lorentzians*)
SeedRandom[0];               (* for reproducibility *)
f[x_] := Evaluate@Tr@
  Table[PDF[CauchyDistribution[a, .0001], x], {a, RandomReal[{.1, .9}, 10]}]        

Plot[Evaluate@f[x], {x, 0, 1}, Filling -> Axis, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We divide the integration regions at the local maxima, up to a tolerance (`10^-12` below, but it should depend on the interval of integration, as well as perhaps `f`).  The function `new` tries to find a new maximum at a starting point, usually the midpoint between two maxima.  The function `subdivide` subdivides the interval if there is a local maximum between the end points, provided the new maximum is significantly different from the end points (governed by the tolerance `1*^-12` in this case).

```
new = FindArgMax[f[x], {x, #}, Method -> {"Newton", "StepControl" -> "TrustRegion"}] &;

subdivide[{a_, b_}] := With[{c = First@new[(a + b)/2]},
  If[a + 1*^-12 < c < b - 1*^-12,
   {subdivide[{a, c}], subdivide[{c, b}]},
   {a, b}]
  ];
```

The integral evaluates without difficulty.

```
NIntegrate[
  f[x],
  {x,
   Sequence @@ Cases[subdivide[{0., 1.}], {a_Real, b_Real} :> a, Infinity],
   1.}] // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {0.30745, 9.99827}  *)
```

The division points, for the curious:

```
Cases[subdivide[{0., 1.}], {a_Real, b_Real} :> a, Infinity]
(* 
  {0., 0.180879, 0.290761, 0.553081, 0.606456, 0.61005,
   0.61642, 0.621974, 0.64625, 0.848162, 0.88095}
*)
```