# NIntegration and GlobalAdaptive method?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, numerics

I integrate with different methods and obtain different results. How to understand which one is correct?

```
T := 20000;
I3s := 1./(2*3^2);
\[Sigma][w_]:=1/(2Pi) 1/(x3s[w]w) 2^9 Pi^3 3^2 (x3s[w])^7 (((x3s[w])^2+1)(7(x3s[w])^2+27)^2)/((x3s[w])^2+9)^6 E^(-4x3s[w]*ArcCot[x3s[w]/3])/(1-E^(-2\[Pi]*x3s[w]));
nB[w_]:=1/(Exp[w/(kB*T)]-1);
G3s := (1.8980259927018785*10^8)/(4.1341*10^16);
x3s[w_] := Sqrt[0.5/(w - I3s)];
```

and finally the integral

```
NIntegrate[w^2 \[Sigma][w]/w Exp[-(w/(kB*T))](w1*nB[w1](G3s/((w-w1)^2+G3s^2/4)+G3s/((w+w1)^2+G3s^2/4))),{w,I3s,Infinity},{w1,0,Infinity}]
```

Download template here https://www.dropbox.com/s/nq2gaqzm09u7jl9/template.nb?dl=0

Comment: Please, post your code to understand what you are doing...

Comment: How to paste mathematica code here?

Comment: When editing your question look at the commands above the edit window. You will see an "{}" icon. Use it...

Comment: What is the value or definition of $G3s$ and `x3s[w]`?

Comment: x3s[w_] := Sqrt[0.5/(w - I3s)]

Comment: T := 20000
I3s := 1./(2*3^2)
G3s := (1.8980259927018785*10^8)/(4.1341*10^16)

Comment: I am assuming that $kB$ is the Boltzman constant in SI unit, right?

Comment: I obtain for your integral, without any convergence error, $0$. I do not know if this is the value you are expecting...

Comment: The parameter `kB` has no definition; both in the post and in the linked notebook at Dropbox. Yes, I see the guess by @JoséAntonioDíazNavas that `kB` might be the Boltzmann constant, but still, I prefer to see an explicit definition.

Comment: kB := 3.16681*10^-6

Comment: I add this constant. Sorry.

Comment: Yes kB is Boltzmann constant in atomic units (Hatree). I have reuploaded new verison of .nb

Comment: Kindly edit your question to include all the additional information you gave in the comments, for completeness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the function, where the major contributions to the integral are. (Attention: This is a Log-Plot)

```
fs[w_, w1_] = 
  FullSimplify[
     w^2 \[Sigma]3sw[w]/
     w Exp[-(w/(kB*T))] (w1*
     nB[w1] (G3s/((w - w1)^2 + G3s^2/4) + 
    G3s/((w + w1)^2 + G3s^2/4))), {w > I3s, w1 > 0}];

Plot3D[Log@fs[w, w1], {w, I3s, 2}, {w1, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotPoints -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 5]
```

[image]

The function peaks at w1 is close to w. (Spikes in the plot are due to low resolution)

```
Plot3D[Log@fs[w, w + r], {w, I3s, 2}, {r, - I3s, I3s}, 
   PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 5]
```

[image]

So you can limit the region of integration

```
NIntegrate[fs[w, w1], {w, I3s, 2}, {w1, w - I3s, w + I3s}, 
   MaxRecursion -> 50]

(*   0.017838   *)
```

Integrate to a higher w, to get slightly better integral.

```
NIntegrate[fs[w, w1], {w, I3s, 4}, {w1, w - I3s, w + I3s}, 
   MaxRecursion -> 50, WorkingPrecision -> 50, PrecisionGoal -> 10, 
   AccuracyGoal -> 10] // Quiet // N[#, 6] &

(*   0.0178421   *)
```

Comment: Your last integral returns multiple errors of type: `The integrand has evaluated to Overflow, Indeterminate, or Infinity for all sampling points in the region with boundaries ...`, How do you get the numerical result then? What is your MMA version? BY using `Method->"LocalAdaptive"` I obtain for your integral the value `2.32069*10^-9`, which is consistent with my result...

Comment: I am using MMA Version 8.0  .  I rationalized all constants, so I can raise `WorkingPrcision ` as high as needed. Try higher WorkingPrecision. I had no problems with the code shown. I find  it no good idea to use `"LocalAdaptive" `and integrate to infinty. It does not recognize the peakline you see in my pictures. Do `re2 = Reap[NIntegrate[.., EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{w, w1, Log@f[w, w1]}]]][[2, 1]]; `with your integral to see, there are not more integration points at the peakline with : `ListPointPlot3D[re2, PlotRange -> {{I3s, 1}, {0, 1}, {-80, 25}}] `  but my integral resolves it exactly.

Comment: No way, even doing what you say. I got the same errors. I have redone it by MonteCarlo and taking a mean of 50 runs, I got `2.26271*10^-6` for your integral. On the other hand, `GlobalAdaptive` is not indicated for peaked functions, more appropriate `LocalAdaptive`, so I cannot figure out why you find it "no good idea"...

Comment: [related](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/107416/using-nintegrate-to-integrate-functions-with-sharp-peaks-lorentzian-like)

Comment: @JoséAntonioDíazNavas Subdividing the interval, as I did in my answer to that related question, I get a result similar to Akku14's.

Comment: Do `$MaxExtraPrecision = 100; NIntegrate[
 fs[w, w1], {w, I3s, 5}, {w1, w - I3s, w +2 I3s}, MaxRecursion -> 50, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 50] ` to get  improved result  `0.017842077692661049574925082 `

Answer (score 4):

Following @Anton Antonov's setup of rationalizing the parameters:

```
Clear[kB, T, I3s, σ, nB, G3s, x3s]
kB = 316681*10^-11;
T = 20000;
I3s = 1/(2*3^2);
σ[w_] := 1/(2 Pi) 1/(x3s[w] w) 2^9 Pi^3 3^2 (x3s[w])^7 (((x3s[w])^2 + 1) (7 (x3s[w])^2 + 27)^2)/((x3s[w])^2 + 9)^6 E^(-4 x3s[w]*ArcCot[x3s[w]/3])/(1 - E^(-2 π*x3s[w]));
nB[w_] := 1/(Exp[w/(kB*T)] - 1);
G3s = (18980259927018785*10^-8)/(41341*10^12);
x3s[w_] := Sqrt[(1/2)/(w - I3s)];
```

#### Addressing the near-singularity

It's not hard to see from a term in the integrand that `w1 == w` has a delta-like, near-singularity:

```
G3s/((w - w1)^2 + G3s^2/4) // N
(*  4.59115*10^-9/(5.26966*10^-18 + (w - 1. w1)^2)  *)
```

If we add `w` to the iterator for `w1`, `NIntegrate` will subdivide the interval at `w`, which will address a substantial part of the problem.

```
NIntegrate[w^2 σ[w]/w *
   Exp[-(w/(kB*T))] (w1*nB[w1] (G3s/((w - w1)^2 + G3s^2/4) + G3s/((w + w1)^2 + G3s^2/4))),
  {w, I3s, Infinity}, {w1, 0, w, Infinity},
  MaxRecursion -> 20, 
  Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "SingularityHandler" -> None}
  ] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> *[No messages]*
>
> ```
> {0.130505, 0.0177845}
> ```

#### Assessing convergence

To test the accuracy, standard tricks include increasing `PrecisionGoal`, `WorkingPrecision`, and sometimes `MinRecursion`.  The default for `PrecisionGoal` on a 2D integral is `6`.  Let's try `8`:

```
NIntegrate[w^2 σ[w]/w *
   Exp[-(w/(kB*T))] (w1*nB[w1] (G3s/((w - w1)^2 + G3s^2/4) + G3s/((w + w1)^2 + G3s^2/4))),
  {w, I3s, Infinity}, {w1, 0, w, Infinity},
  MaxRecursion -> 20, PrecisionGoal -> 8, 
  Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "SingularityHandler" -> None}
  ] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.
>
> ```
> {0.936032, 0.0178419}
> ```

The message `NIntegrate::slwcon` is just a warning and does not indicate an error.  In both cases, there was no message indicating that the error goals were not met.  However, there is a large difference between the two results, a difference in the 3rd significant figure.  This suggests the error estimate is not accurate and casts some doubt on the convergence of numerical integration. Considering the advice in the message, the integrand does not appear to be oscillating and so it could be that the `WorkingPrecision` is too small.  I've also found in such cases that increasing `MinRecursion` can remove the warning.  Increasing it causes denser sampling throughout the domain, which can help the error estimate.  (It has the downside of increasing sampling in places where it's not needed. For each increment of `1`, it usually doubles the sampling in each dimension, so the sampling grows exponentially with the level of recursion.)

Usually I do these things step-by-step by hand and think about the results at each step.  But here's a way to increase `MinRecursion` until it does no more good.  It compares one level with the previous level until the relative change is less than `10^-6`.  Hence it overshoots the maximum useful `MinRecursion`, and we have to step it back at the end.

```
ClearAll[nonconvQ];
nonconvQ[{___, r1_, r2_}] := Abs[(r1 - r2)/(10^-16 + 10^-6 r1)] > 1;
nonconvQ[{___}] := True;

PrintTemporary@Dynamic@{mr, Clock[Infinity]};  (* monitor *)
mr = 0;    (* initial value for MinRecursion *)
pg = 8;    (* PrecisionGoal *)
mrresults = {};
Print[PrecisionGoal -> pg];  (* to remind me/check that it's set as desired *)
While[nonconvQ@mrresults && mr <= 10,  (* upper limit of 10 *)
  AppendTo[
   mrresults,
   Check[
    res = NIntegrate[
      w^2 σ[w]/w Exp[-(w/(kB*T))] *
       (w1*nB[w1] (G3s/((w - w1)^2 + G3s^2/4) + G3s/((w + w1)^2 + G3s^2/4))),
      {w, I3s, Infinity}, {w1, 0, w, Infinity},
      MinRecursion -> mr, MaxRecursion -> 20, PrecisionGoal -> pg,
      Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "SingularityHandler" -> None}],
    Print[MinRecursion -> mr]; res]
   ];
  mr += 2;
  ] // AbsoluteTiming
mr = mr - 4
```

> ```
> PrecisionGoal->8
> ```
>
> NIntegrate::slwcon: ....
>
> ```
> MinRecursion->0
> ```
>
> NIntegrate::slwcon: ....
>
> ```
> MinRecursion->2
> ```
>
> NIntegrate::slwcon: ....
>
> General::stop: ....
>
> ```
> MinRecursion->4
>
> {2.97894, Null}
>
> 2  (* <-- mr *)
> ```

We found that `MinRecursion -> 2` is the best, although we still get `NIntegrate::slwcon` warnings.  (What works may also depend on the `PrecisionGoal` and `WorkingPrecision`, but this gives us a good starting point.)  We can examine the results and their differences:

```
mrresults

{0.017841865511943975`,
  0.01784207781124873`,
  0.01784207380554739`} // Differences

(*  {2.12299*10^-7, -4.0057*10^-9}  *)
```

So let's try raising `WorkingPrecision`.  I usually double machine precision as a first try, to `30` or `32`.  To see whether `WorkingPrecision -> 30` is working, we can increasingly raise `PrecisionGoal`.  Instead of checking for convergence as we did for `MinRecursion`, we'll examine the results stored in `hpg` (High PrecisionGoal) for stability.  The differences of the results show that the last two results for `PrecisionGoal` of `10` and `12` agree to `9` significant digits; probably, therefore, a precision goal of at least `9` has been reached in the final result.

```
PrintTemporary@Dynamic@{pg2, Clock[Infinity]};  (* monitor *)
Print[MinRecursion -> mr];  (* check it's set as desired (mr determined in prev. code) *)
hpg = Table[
    Check[
     res = NIntegrate[
       w^2 σ[w]/w Exp[-(w/(kB*T))] *
        (w1*nB[w1] (G3s/((w - w1)^2 + G3s^2/4) + G3s/((w + w1)^2 + G3s^2/4))),
        {w, I3s, Infinity}, {w1, 0, w, Infinity},
        MinRecursion -> mr, MaxRecursion -> 20,
        PrecisionGoal -> pg2, WorkingPrecision -> 30,
        Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "SingularityHandler" -> None}],
     Print[PrecisionGoal -> pg2]; res],
    {pg2, pg, 12, 2}  (* tries 8, 10, 12 *)
    ]; // AbsoluteTiming
hpg
```

> ```
> MinRecursion->2
>
> {279.558, Null}
>
> {0.0178419717276098694849061712810,  (* these are the results in hpg *)
>  0.0178420778761599013231241349024,
>  0.0178420779116383260908787283014} // Differences
>
> {1.061485500318382179636214*10^-7, 3.54784247677545933990*10^-11} (* Differences@hpg *)
> ```

This shows that @Akku14's result of `0.0178421` seems accurate to the digits shown.

Comment: However, I still would like an explanation of why by using `LocalAdaptive`, or `MonteCarlo`, one obtain so different result...If I do the same as you, I obtain your result, but the OP question was related about the reliability of the result of `NIntegrate` by using different methods, i.e., what is the correct result?

Comment: @JoséAntonioDíazNavas I think the erroneous results in both cases are explained in [this tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationRules.html#8354729).  I think `"LocalAdaptive"` does work, esp. if you use `{w1, 0, w, Infinity}`, but not as well as `"GlobalAdaptive"`, as explained [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationStrategies.html#558182960).

Comment: I'm not sure why one would think `"MonteCarlo"` would work after seeing Akku's plot. When the support is more spread out, one expects convergence to be roughly $\sigma/\sqrt{n}$, where $\sigma$ is a bound on the standard deviation of the $n$ random function samples. I don't know how having such a skewed distribution affects the error, but I'd guess it makes it worse. It also makes it more likely that the sampling will missed the support along the line `w == w1`.

Comment: Note `AccuracyGoal -> 5` would make it stop when the absolute error estimate is below `10^-5`, which is likely to happen with a small sample size. You might need a sample size over `10^10`, maybe 10^14 to get a smallish error. This works somewhat `NIntegrate[integrand, {w, I3s, 0.31}, {w1, 0, w, 0.31}, Method -> {"MonteCarlo", "MaxPoints" -> 10^7}]`, although it varies wildly with each evaluation.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. However, I know and read that tutorial, and there is no place whether it is clear that `GlobalAdaptive` is better than `LocalAdaptive`. Further "In **general** the global adaptive strategy has better performance than the local adaptive one. **In some cases though, the local adaptive strategy is more robust and/or gives better performance.**". Thus, why is not the analysed case one of those? Why does not it overestimate the integral by subdividing the intervals and doing `GlobalAdaptive` with `GaussKronrodRule`?

Comment: @JoséAntonioDíazNavas I'm sure you'll learn a lot figuring that out. I suppose all it takes is some analysis of the integrand. [`IntegrationMonitor` and `NIntegrateSamplingPoints`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/96663/4999) should be of help. This may also be helpful: [Genz and Malik](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/0720038).

Comment: @JoséAntonioDíazNavas It occurs to me that I might be unclear what you mean by "better." I thought [the tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationStrategies.html#290792217) clearly shows that global-adaptive needed fewer function evaluations than local-adaptive to achieve high accuracy on the examples shown.

Answer (score 1):

As @JoséAntonioDíazNavas mentioned it seems that your integral is zero, or very close to zero.

Using these definitions with rationalized numbers:

```
Clear[kB, T, I3s, \[Sigma], nB, G3s, x3s]
kB = 316681*10^-11;
T = 20000;
I3s = 1/(2*3^2);
\[Sigma][w_] := 
  1/(2 Pi) 1/(x3s[w] w) 2^9 Pi^3 3^2 (x3s[
      w])^7 (((x3s[w])^2 + 1) (7 (x3s[w])^2 + 27)^2)/((x3s[w])^2 + 
       9)^6 E^(-4 x3s[w]*ArcCot[x3s[w]/3])/(1 - E^(-2 \[Pi]*x3s[w]));
nB[w_] := 1/(Exp[w/(kB*T)] - 1);
G3s = (18980259927018785*10^-8)/(41341*10^12);
x3s[w_] := Sqrt[(1/2)/(w - I3s)];
```

I get the following estimates.

```
NIntegrate[
 w^2 \[Sigma][w]/
   w Exp[-(w/(kB*T))] (w1*
    nB[w1] (G3s/((w - w1)^2 + G3s^2/4) + 
      G3s/((w + w1)^2 + G3s^2/4))), {w, I3s, Infinity}, {w1, 0, 
  Infinity}, 
 Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "MaxErrorIncreases" -> 10000, 
   "SingularityHandler" -> None}, MinRecursion -> 4, 
 MaxRecursion -> 20, WorkingPrecision -> 30, PrecisionGoal -> 4]

 (* NIntegrate::slwcon ...*)
 (* NIntegrate::eincr...
    NIntegrate obtained 0.0000366543148899549212924804766952`30. and \
     6.18910712643431633973726009426`30.*^-6 for the integral and error \
    estimates.
  *)
 (* 0.0000366543148899549212924804766952 *)


NIntegrate[
 w^2 \[Sigma][w]/
   w Exp[-(w/(kB*T))] (w1*
    nB[w1] (G3s/((w - w1)^2 + G3s^2/4) + 
      G3s/((w + w1)^2 + G3s^2/4))), {w, I3s, Infinity}, {w1, 0, 
  Infinity}, 
 Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", Method -> "GaussKronrodRule", 
   "MaxErrorIncreases" -> 10000}, MinRecursion -> 4, 
 MaxRecursion -> 20]

(* NIntegrate::slwcon...
   NIntegrate::pincer...
   NIntegrate obtained 0.0002643264047745091` and    0.0000943240383048598` \
   for the integral and error estimates.*)
 (* 0.0002643264047745091 *)
```

You can experiment with using higher precision and "MaxErrorIncreases" and see do you consistently get closer to 0. (Or any other value...)

Answer (score 0):

By using your definitions in the notebook provided, I have done:

```
NIntegrate[
w^2 \[Sigma]3sw[w]/
w^1 Exp[-(w/(kB*T))] (w1^1*
nB[w1] (G3s/((w - w1)^2 + G3s^2/4) + 
  G3s/((w + w1)^2 + G3s^2/4))), {w, I3s, Infinity}, {w1, 0, Infinity},
MinRecursion -> 40, MaxRecursion -> 50, 
Method -> {"LocalAdaptive", Method -> "MultidimensionalRule"}, 
PrecisionGoal -> \[Infinity], AccuracyGoal -> 5]

(* 1.50775*10^-8 *)
```

The result was obtained with no errors. I used MMA 11.3 and macOS 10.13.13